# Minimal perfect hashing of integers in base two range

Tags: c, hash, integer, range, perfect

I'm after a simple hash function that would take an integer within a range of base two and (randomly) hash to another integer within that range without collisions. This is going to be used to construct a permutation and preferably from a seed value. So just offsetting the integer and modulating won't work. Anyone know of a good option written in C?

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: Hi! I recall something involving symmetric groups. I can check it tomorrow, but maybe you find something here, if you want to check in the meantime: https://books.google.de/books?id=hxFqdbfc_CMC&printsec=frontcover&dq=permutation+group+algorithms&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-6LeD2qHPAhWG2hoKHTgzBMQQ6AEIJzAA#v=onepage&q=permutation%20group%20algorithms&f=false

Comment: Thanks @fr_andres, I'll have a look through it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a good solution in the paper [Correlated Multi-Jittered Sampling](https://graphics.pixar.com/library/MultiJitteredSampling/paper.pdf) by Andrew Kensler. Here a permutation is constructed using a mixing function only consisting of reversible operators. This guarantees there to be no collisions within a power of two range.

The function was found iteratively by using a hill-climbing program that evaluates each candidate according to it's avalaunch property. Furthermore, Kensler generalizes the hash to allow for ranges that are not a power of two by using a technique called cycle walking.

Due to this, the quality of the result and also the ability to easily scramble the permutation, the proposed function is a good solution to the original question. See Bret Mulveyʼs article on hash functions [here](http://papa.bretmulvey.com/post/124027987928/hash-functions) for further details on reversible operators and generating quality mixing functions.

Comment: nice! i will check it

Answer (score 2):

This may help (see the bottom for a more general approach): the [multiplicative cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group#Modular_multiplication) allow you to pick a `k` "seed" value, a `n` "maximum" value, and permutate the natural numbers from zero to n-1 in a very efficient way (k can be in Z but preferibly both natural numbers). The only gotcha, if you want a permutation, is that `n` has to be a prime number, and I'm not sure if all permutations are uniformly distributed around the seed space (some knowledge on [cryptography](https://www.schneierfacts.com/facts/1101) would help here a lot).

The main operation would then be something like this, in pseudocode:

```
for i in range(0, n){ i:= (i*k)(mod n);}
```

and here a working toy-program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  // take a prime number (from https://primes.utm.edu/lists/2small/0bit.html)
  //int n = (int)pow(2,13)-1;
  // for the sake of test, let's take a little one:
  int n = 23;
  // take a random integer seed:
  int k = 1234;
  printf("permutation of numbers from 0 below %d with seed %d:\n", n, k);
  for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%d ", ((i*k)%n));
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

which returns:

```
permutation of numbers from 0 below 23 with seed 1234:
0 15 7 22 14 6 21 13 5 20 12 4 19 11 3 18 10 2 17 9 1 16 8
```

This isn't exactly what you want, but with some tweaks it could work OK... unless we're talking about high-end security stuff. Probably the most straightforward solution would be to pick the primes that are close to the power of two, and do some tweaking?
https://primes.utm.edu/lists/2small/

Let me know if it helps!

**EDIT** I couldn't help to directly test it on my emacs, so here is the function for the posterity:

```
(defun permute (n seed)
  "prints a permutation of the set of numbers between 0 and n-1, 
   provided n is prime"
  (let ((permuted (loop for i below n collect (% (* i seed) n))))
    (print permuted)
    ;(print (sort permuted '<)) ; debug print
    ))

(test 23  1234) ; returns (0 15 7 22 14 6 21 13 5 20 12 4 19 11 3 18 10 2 17 9 1 16 8)
```

**EDIT 2**
Actually, it would suffice that `k` and `n` are prime to each other, as stated in [Bézout's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity). So technically, you could have arbitrary natural values for `n` if you ensure that. A straightforward, but limited way would be to random pick `k` from a list of prime numbers. A maybe better solution would be to calculate for each given `n` its relative primes, and pick from there (aclaration: neither 8 nor 9 are primes, but they are prime to each other because 9(mod 8)= 1). It doesn't get much more "complete" than that, but I still don't know how the permutations are distributed with this approach.

Comment: for example, if you don't want the 0 to be mapped to 0, you can add any random integer to all results, and then compute modulo n again... such tweaks

Comment: Thanks for looking that up @fr_andres, this looks like a good solution despite the limitation. I'm using it as a permutation of an interval within a (t,s)-sequence, and 2^7 is a reasonable size.

Comment: cool! :) as I said, there are some dirty workarounds so let me know if it suffices... would be great anyway if you can share your solution. Cheers

Comment: Yeah I'll share any other solution that comes up, will keep an eye out for something more generalised. Thanks

Comment: I believe that if your `k` (seed) is prime, your `n` can be abritrary. But then the permutation space would be clearly smaller...

Comment: I've changed the accepted answer as I've come across another solution that produces less visible correlation. That said, it is also more expensive to evaluate so this may still be a better option if performance is more important.